# Get constraint based url using url_for based on mounted engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actiondispatch

Is there any way that i can make url_for to return the url based on the request.host during action dispatch routing ?

```
mount Collaborate::Engine => '/apps/collaborate', :constraints => {:host => 'example.com' }
mount Collaborate::Engine => '/apps/worktogether'
```

Example:

When the user is on example.com host

> collaborate_path => /apps/collaborate

When the user is on any other host

> collaborate_path => /apps/worktogether

After a lot of research, i realize that RouteSet class has named_routes which does not consider the constraints to return the url.

I've tried overriding @set in action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb to pickup from rails application but dint work as expected

```
@search_set = Rails.application.routes.set.routes.select{|x| x.defaults[:host] == options[:host] }[0]
@set = @search_set unless @search_set.blank?
```

Answer (score 7):

## Remove .com in your example

```
mount Collaborate::Engine => '/apps/collaborate', :constraints => {:host => 'examplesite' }
mount Collaborate::Engine => '/apps/worktogether'
```

Should just work

If you need a more advanced constraint, make your own constraint:

```
class CustomConstraint
  def initialize
    # Things you need for initialization
  end

  def matches?(request)
    # Do your thing here with the request object
    # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object
    request.host == "example"
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'foo', to: 'bar#baz',
    constraints: CustomConstraint.new
end
```

You can also specify constraints as a lambda:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'foo', to: 'foo#bar',
    constraints: lambda { |request| request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1' }
end
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Answer (score 2):

As for as my concern if you handle it at middleware level then it would be good. This is what my assumption.

Add this line in **`config/application.rb`**

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "SelectiveStack"
```

Add a middleware in app directory with middleware directory as a Convention

**`app/middleware/selective_stack.rb`**

```
class SelectiveStack
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    debugger
    if env["SERVER_NAME"] == "example.com"
      "/apps/collaborate"
    else
      "/apps/worktogether"
    end
  end


end
```

Hope this will solve your issue.!!!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's a shot in the dark; maybe you've tried it already or maybe I'm really missing something.  On the surface, it really looks like you're just trying to override a path helper method for `apps`.  So why not set up an override in the `application_helper.rb`?  Something like:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def collaborate_path
    if request.domain == "example.com"
      "/apps/collaborate"
    else
      "/apps/worktogether"
    end
  end
end
```